# Is it safe to use the same password for both VeraCrypt volume and Windows Login?

Tags: passwords, password-based-encryption

I encrypted my entire volume with Veracrypt which prompts on start up and asks for a password, great.

Now after every startup is finished or everytime I leave the computer unattended (after a quick Windows key+L) there is only the Windows password to protect my computer so is it safe to use the same password for both vera and windows considering how full of glitches and backdoors windows is?

Thanks

Comment: One of the password checking methods will be weaker than the other, but neither are obviously bad. The safety will depend on your threat model, how likely is it that someone will install a keylogger inside your keyboard?

Comment: This is an IT security best practices question, and in a sense not a cryptography question.  Obviously, if the password for Windows gets compromised (e.g. by shouldersurifing or a brute force attack), the Veracrypt password is (and vice versa, but it matters less). So no that's not best practice. Tip: consider what's chosen as memorable secret for encryption a passphrase, not a password. That helps